# Spring SimpleJdbcCall calling stored procedure without input parameter but with output parameter

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I trying to call a stored procedure which only has one out parameter and no input parameter. When I call the stored procedure as shown below, I get "wrong number or types of arguments in call to" error

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(springTemplate) 
.withCatalogName("my_package").withProcedureName("my_procedure")
.withReturnValue().withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
.declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("return", Types.VARCHAR));
 Map out = jdbcCall.execute();
 System.out.println((String)out.get("return"));
```

I am not sure whats wrong here.I get the error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; 
bad SQL   grammar [{? = call my_package.my_procedure()}]; nested exception is 
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my_procedure'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

Any help will be very much appreciated
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 4):

I tried exactly what you did and it worked for me, please post the result of the following statement:

```
select PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, POSITION, ARGUMENT_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IN_OUT
from USER_ARGUMENTS
where PACKAGE_NAME ='my_package' and OBJECT_NAME = 'my_procedure'
order by PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, POSITION
```

Update:
I think I found your mistake, quote *'a stored procedure which only has one out parameter and no input parameter'*. You have a procedure, not a function. In that case you have to write:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(springTemplate) 
    .withCatalogName("my_package")
    .withProcedureName("my_procedure")
    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
    .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("YOUR_OUTPARAMETER_NAME", Types.VARCHAR));
```

Comment: Its easy to mix up withProcedureName and withFunctionName